# GigE Camera/MIL Library - Part of image gets cut

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision

I am currently working on a software which uses a GigE Camera to record light spectra and do some analysis with them. But because this analysis is time-consuming, part of it is already done on an FPGA. One record of the camera has a format of 320 x 256 (320 spectra with 256px). The FPGA takes this record and multiplies it with a 256 x 1 matrix, so the end result is a 320 x 1 matrix. This result is a column vector and it would fit exactly into the dimensions. But unfortunately it is shown as a row vector, so from 256 on everything is cut.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiRKR.png

So I tried to set the width dimension different:

```
MdigControl(MilDigitizer, M_SOURCE_SIZE_X, 320);
```

But I get an error, because the height and width attributes of the camera are read-only.
Interestingly, when using the free version of the eBus Player from Pleora Technologies, it works! I get a result of 1 x 320.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrBEo.png

Can anybody help?

Thank you

EDIT:
The following code shows the allocation and display of an image.

```
MappAlloc(M_DEFAULT, &MilApplication);
MsysAlloc(M_SYSTEM_GIGE_VISION, M_DEV0, M_DEFAULT, &MilSystem);
MdispAlloc(MilSystem, M_DEFAULT, MIL_TEXT("M_DEFAULT"), M_WINDOWED, &MilDisplay);
MdigAlloc(MilSystem, M_DEV0, MIL_TEXT("M_DEFAULT"), M_DEFAULT, &MilDigitizer);
MbufAllocColor(MilSystem, 3, 320, 1, 8+M_UNSIGNED, M_IMAGE+M_GRAB+M_DISP, &MilImageRGB);

unsigned char *testArray = new unsigned char[320*3];
MdigGrab(MilDigitizer, &MilImageRGB);

// Print values
MbufGetColor(MilImageRGB, M_PLANAR, M_ALL_BANDS, testArray);
for(int counterColorBand = 0; counterColorBand < 3; counterColorBand++)
{
  for(int counterPosition = 0; counterPosition < 320; counterPosition++)
  {
    std::cout << counterColorBand*320 + counterPosition << "-" << static_cast<unsigned>(testArray[counterColorBand * 320 + counterPosition]) << "\t";
  }
  std::cout << "\n\n";
}

//Display image
MdispSelect(MilDisplay, &MilImageRGB);
```

Comment: What SDK are you using to get the images from the camera? You might need to include more code in your question too.

Comment: I am using the MIL-Lite 9.00 R2+ 64-bit. I added more code.

Comment: So is the problem you're having purely on the display of the calculated matrix? Because I don't see the original line of code you mentioned in that block of code you've added. Is rotating it before display not an option?

Comment: Yep the first line of code is not there because it would result in an error. The code below results in an image of 1 x 256, although the buffer is allocated with 1 x 320, because MIL only records pictures of 320 x 256 and so it just takes out the first line of 1 x 256.
Rotating, sadly, is not an option, because it changes the matrix multiplication:
320 x 256 * 256 x 1, works,
256 x 320 * 256 x 1, doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem through getting in contact with the Matrox customer service and I thought I let you know:
The problem was, that before I was actually receiving data it was stored on an internal memory, which uses the dimensions of 320x256px. Through some code this can be avoided:

```
MIL_INT64 Format = 0;
MdigInquire(MilDigitizer, M_SOURCE_BUFFER_FORMAT, &Format)
...
MbufAllocColor(…, 3, 1, 320, 8+M_UNSIGNED, M_IMAGE+M_GRAB+Format, …);
```